# how do I echo a message to the terminal at the end of npm install?

Tags: npm, echo, npm-install, npm-scripts

I've created a repo I want to be cloned 
after cloning, you run `npm install`

How do I `echo` a log message to the ***terminal*** that will show up at the end of the installation?

Comment: npm install && echo done npm install

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you can add a post-install script, that outputs, for example, a string to the console if you mark a version as alpha.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "version": "1.2.3-alpha.2",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node postinstall.js"
  }
}
```

**postinstall.js**

```js
const package = require('./package.json')

console.log('End of installation');

//Example using properties from package.json
if (package.version.includes('alpha')) {
  console.log('Warning: Alpha version!')
}
```

**BONUS**

Append this to the command `--loglevel verbose` and all logs will be saved to  `npm-debug.log` in current working directory.

It will show the logs in realtime + saves the log to directory its running.

You can just edit npm config `npm config edit` and add `loglevel=verbose`